# While loop in IBM DB2 stored procedure endup in infinite looping

Tags: stored-procedures, while-loop, db2

I am new with procedure. Somewhat I am getting the results too. But I got problem with a dynamic query. Stored query in a variable and tried to execute using cursor. But the loop only select the first result and execute infinitely. I couldn't find the error. How can I clear the error? Any help would be appreciated.

**My Procedure is**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SPTEST1(IN tr_code INT, IN pen_type INT, IN pen_code INT, IN due_code INT, IN ord_dt DATE, IN finyr_cd INT, IN user_id varchar(50), IN server_ip varchar(100), OUT res INTEGER)
SPECIFIC sptest1
LANGUAGE SQL

P1:BEGIN
    DECLARE trcd INTEGER;
    DECLARE pentyp INTEGER;
    DECLARE pencd INTEGER;
    DECLARE duecd INTEGER;
    DECLARE orddt DATE;
    DECLARE finyrcd INTEGER;
    DECLARE userid VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE serverip VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE ls_pentype CHAR(1);
    DECLARE ls_voted CHAR(1);
    DECLARE li_crmonth INTEGER;
    DECLARE li_cryear INTEGER;
    DECLARE ls_adhoc CHAR(1);
    DECLARE ld_elgdt DATE;
    DECLARE li_duecode INTEGER;
    DECLARE li_headid INTEGER;
    DECLARE tr_whr varchar(500);
    DECLARE code_whr varchar(500);
    DECLARE sqlstmt varchar(1000);
    DECLARE EOF int DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE v_duplicate INT DEFAULT 0;--
    DECLARE c_duplicate CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '23505';
    DECLARE STMT VARCHAR(120);
    DECLARE SQLCODE INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE SQLSTATE CHAR(5) DEFAULT '00000';

    SET trcd = tr_code;
    SET pentyp = pen_type;
    SET pencd = pen_code;
    SET duecd = due_code;
    SET orddt = ord_dt;
    SET finyrcd = finyr_cd;
    SET userid = user_id;
    SET serverip = server_ip;
    SET ls_voted = 'V';

    IF duecd > 50 THEN
        SET ls_voted = 'C';
    END IF;
    FOR v_row AS <select query>
        DO
        SET ls_pentype = v_row.fmly_serv_oth_pen;
    END FOR;
    FOR date_month AS <select query>
        DO
        SET li_crmonth = date_month.credit_month;
        SET li_cryear = date_month.credit_year;
    END FOR;
    FOR adhoc_row AS <select query>
        DO
        SET ls_adhoc = adhoc_row.is_adhoc_due;
    END FOR;
    FOR elgdt_row AS <select query>
        DO
        SET ld_elgdt = elgdt_row.eligible_uptodt;
    END FOR;
    FOR head_row AS <select query>
        DO
        SET li_headid = head_row.head_id;
        SET li_duecode = duecd;
    END FOR;
    --portion for delete. have to enter
    P2:BEGIN
        DECLARE TRPOC CURSOR FOR <select query>

        OPEN TRPOC;
            FETCH FROM TRPOC INTO trcd;
            WHILE(SQLSTATE = '00000') DO
                insert into bg_run_test values(char(trcd));
                END WHILE;
        CLOSE TRPOC;        
    END P2;
END P1@
```

Here the while loop at the last executing infinitely. Where I try to insert in a table. Actually the result have only 200 rows.But inserting lacks.

Comment: Side note: if possible, avoid loops in SQL, especially when issuing queries and statements.    It may be possible to write this entire thing as one `INSERT` statement that contains the `SELECT`s and their data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need an additional FETCH at the end of the WHILE loop after the INSERT statement, for it to successfully break out.

See this [link](http://catterallconsulting.blogspot.com/2009/07/sql-programming-nugget-sqlstate-and.html?_sm_au_=iQV6MR0KM7FvSs1r) which explains exactly this scenario.

Comment: thanks a lot.. That worked like a charm..I had spend around 2 days for this answer.. Thank you again